# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

console shows me the following error "type error cannot read property addeventlistner of null" my script is in the end of the page.How to clear the null value make click and function run here.Cant find solution mostly the error is placing script in the head but i have placed in the bottom from beginning.help me learn this issue and solve !!!

```
     <div class="form">
       <label for="guessField">Enter a guess: </label>
       <input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit guess" class="guessSubmit">
    </div>

  <p class="guesses"></p>
  <p class="lastResult"></p>
  <p class="lowOrHi"></p>
<script>

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    var userguess = document.querySelector('.guessField');

    var userSubmit = document.querySelector('guessSubmit');

    var guesses = document.querySelector('guesses');

    var lastResult = document.querySelector('lastResult');

    var lowOrHi = document.querySelector('lowOrHi');

    var guesscount = 1;

    var resetbutton;

    function checkGuess() {

        var userinput = Number(userguess.value);

        if (guesscount === 1) {
            guesses.textContent = 'previous guesses:';
        }
        else {
            guesses.textContent = 'previous guesses' + userinput;
        }

        if (userinput === random) {

            lastResult.textContent = "awesome bruh you got it right";
            lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            gameOver();
        }

        else if (guesscount === 10) {
            lastResult.textContent = "oops you have run out of try";
            gameOver();
        }

        else {
            lastResult.textContent = "wrong value";
            lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }

        if (userinput < random) {
            lowOrHi.textContent = "it was too low";
        }

        else if (userinput > random) {
            lowOrHi.textContent = "it was too high";
        }

        guesscount++;
    }

    userSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkGuess);

</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the html?

Comment: 1. Show the full html.. 2. On which line do you get the error? EDIT: looks like you forgot dots before class names

Comment: I'm gonna guess and say you're not using `querySelctor` correctly. This function uses [CSS Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) style syntax,

Comment: html added @EleazarEnrique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to update all your selectors properly. You are missing `.`/`#` in some of them.

```
var userSubmit = document.querySelector('.guessSubmit');
//                                   ----^----
// add `.` or `#` based on what guessSubmit selector is for
```

Comment: it worked @palash thx

Comment: happy new year :)